# Java convert long to 4 bytes

Tags: java, arrays, byte, long-integer, unsigned

How do I convert long to 4 bytes? I am receiving some output from a C program and it uses unsigned long. I need to read this output and convert this to 4 bytes.

However, java uses signed long which is 64 bits. Is there any way to do this conversion?

Comment: You cant because of singed bit. Why not use long as it is? If this is for optimization then you should not bothered about.

Comment: `int` is signed 32-bit in Java, which would seem more appropriate than the 64-bit `long`. Also, **how** are you passing the data from C to Java?

Comment: It would seem more appropriate if you do the `long unsigned int` to `byte[4]` conversion in C and pass it (could be a comma-separated integer list) to Java.

Answer (score 9):

To read 4 bytes as an unsigned 32-bit value, assuming it is little endian, the simplest thing to do is to use ByteBuffer

```
byte[] bytes = { 1,2,3,4 };
long l = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes)
                   .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt() & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
```

While `l` can be an signed 64-bit value it will only be between 0 and 2^^32-1 which is the range of a unsigned 32-bit value.

Comment: Just a quick note. The mask should be 0x0FFFFFFFFL to keep from getting the extended sign bit.

Comment: @Zagrev 0x0FFFFFFFFL == 0xFFFFFFFFL Literals are not sign extended, they will be the value you set.

Comment: ah! I stand corrected. This bit me so many times in my past it's just a reflex now.

Comment: so is it useful to add the & 0xFFFFFFFFL; ??

Comment: @mou for masking `unsigned int` values, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can code a loop where you divide the "long" by 256, take the rest, then you have the "Least Significant Byte" ...
(depending on whether you want little-endian or big-endian you can loop forwards or backwards)

```
  long l = (3* 256 * 256 * 256 + 1 * 256 *256 + 4 * 256 + 8);
  private byte[] convertLongToByteArray(long l) {
      byte[] b = new byte[4];
      if(java.nio.ByteOrder.nativeOrder() == ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN){
          for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            b[i] = (byte)(l % 256) ;
            l = l / 256;
          }
     }else{
          for (int i=3; i>=0; i--) {
            b[i] = (byte)(l % 256) ;
            l = l / 256;
          }
     }
      return b;
  }
```

Comment: Come off it. The method is useless unless it takes a long parameter. With a hard coded input you may as well hardcore the output.

Comment: @EJP Come on, it doesn't look bad as an example. This could leave the OP some thinking space.

Comment: @EJP This was just an example. One just needed to declare a variable and then pass it in the method. Anyways, i updated the code

Answer (score 1):

You can use the java.nio.ByteBuffer. It can parse the long, and it does the byte ordering for you.

Comment: long is 8 bytes in java. ByteBuffer will wrap it in 8 bytes

Comment: ByteBuffer will give it back to you however you want it. I answered this because he said he's getting the data from a C program, and that means byte order will be important too.

Comment: Yes, you are right but the major concern was to convert long to 4 bytes which will not be fulfilled by this solution

Comment: I read that is converting a long to byte[4]. Is that not what was asked? If all was are doing is truncating a long to an int, that's too easy.